# MYSQL query returning incorrect results in my web application

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get list of people who have applied for particular category which is active but I'm not able to get the proper result

**Below is my query which i have tried**

```
$Query = mysql_query("select s_p_I.name,p_s.Seatno,t_s
                      from student_pers_info s_p_I, pat_students p_s,test_score t_s,current_category c_c,candidate_selected_category c_s_c
                      where (s_p_I.pat_code=p_s.pat_code)
                          && (s_p_i.pat_code =t_s.pat_code)
                          && (c_c.category_code =c_s_c.category_code) 
                          && (c_c.active = c_s_c.active) = 1")
```

Problem occurs at last condition it brings all records who all are in candidate_selected_category table a and having active value 1

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_` functions as they are both [deprecated and a security risk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Please learn to use code formatting.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query for guidance on how to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is missing somethin at the end of this line:

```
select s_p_I.name,p_s.Seatno,t_s
```

(there should be a field name after `t_s`)

And in the second line you should use JOINs for the different tables you select from